# Designing a timer functionality in VC++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, visual-c++

I was implemnting some functionaliy in which i get a set of queries on database  One shouldnt loose the query for a certain time lets say some 5min unless and untill the query is executed fine (this is incase the DB is down, we dont loose the query). so, what i was thinking to do is to set a sort of timer for each query through a different thread and wait on it for that time frame, and at the end if it still exists, remove it from the queue, but, i am not happy with this solution as i have to create as many threads as the number of queries. is there a better way to design this (environment is vc++), If the question is unclear, please let me know, i will try to frame it better.

Comment: so, you want to add basically timeout functionality to a query, however, your current method, which is to spawn a new thread per query, your unsatisfied with, to clarify?

Comment: Why you need separate thread for each timer? Just store due time now + 5 min.

Comment: @Luke : Yes, I am currently placing all the queries in a queue and will remove them in 2 cases. 1. if the query is executed successfully 2. If the timeout happens on the thread.

Comment: @ÖöTiib : Sorry, i am sort of unclear on your statement. Like i said in the prev statement and the question, each query should be kept alive for certain time to consider the database downtime. So, each query should have a timer associated with it. I am achieving this timer functionality through a thread. And i am looking out for a better solution ..

Comment: That is what I am not sure why? Windows has timers that send messages and timers that are wait-able. None of those needs separate threads. Clean-up of obsolete timed out stuff can be done as lowest priority task now and then from single thread. Only thing that you need is to be able to decide if something is around with "best before" over. So add that data into your queue.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: i understand, Isnt there a self destruction possible, instead of polling at certain time interval ?. I would defly give ur idea a try .. But, would like to know if a query can be deleted at the exact time ...

Comment: Self destruction is possible for active objects (that have thread or share thread pool). A query does not sound like one. Non-active objects may put timed request to destroy them to some active object and revoke that request if they destruct before. That is all possible but complex, better keep it simple. Just have some janitor who checks the queue now and then and cleans garbage from dirty end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thread is enough to check lets say every 10 seconds that you do not have queries in that queue of yours whose due time has been reached and so should be aborted / rolled back.

Queues are usually grown from one end and erased from other end so you have to check only if the query on the end where the oldest items are has not reached its due time.